# How can you remove whitespace between a class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way I can remove the whitespace in a class, meaning `<li class="Hello Jonny"></li>`  should be `<li class="hellojonny"></li>`

Here is what i tried but no luck as I am totally new to Javascript & coming from a graphic background

```
        var myTextAll = $('li').text();
        var myRemoveSpaceAll = myTextAll.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Also if hellojonny is in small caps. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: `<li class="Hello Jonny"></li>` means that the <li> is part of the `Hello` class and also part of the `Jonny` class. If that is not the intention, why is there whitespace in the first place? This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/), can you clarify where the HTML in question is coming from?

Comment: Are you sure you can do it in an automated way? For example, if you have other `<li>` elements with other classes, simply removing the space would not give the desired result (e.g. `<li class="Hello Johnny foo">`, would become `<li class="hellojohnnyfoo">` instead of `<li class="hellojohnny foo">`)

Comment: Don't use JS for this. Fix it at the source - ie. either in the HTML, or the server side code which creates the incorrect `class` value.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt reply and suggestions. @RoryMcCrossan , I though the menu was coming dynamically as its a wordpress website, then did a search and noticed the menu was put there as a static ul li. Website is done by someone else & also .hellojonny class is already there so was looking for a quick solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to fix at the source. But if you really need an automated way you could loop through all the list elements classes and replace the text.

```
for (i = 0; i < $("li").length; i++) {
     // Get the initial text of every list item
     let initialText = $("li").eq(i).attr("class");
     // Remove the whitespace and convert to lower case
     let newText = initialText.replace(/ /g, "").toLowerCase();
     // Set the list item class to the new text
     $("li").eq(i).attr("class", newText);
}
```